# Temperature color?

Tags: display

I managed to change the gamma with redshift, but it change the color of the screen and I do not want it to do that function.

How do I make the color of the screen using redshift normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the top of the redshift.conf file (line 4 & 5 most likely) there are temperature settings for day and night. Set them both to around 6500 and you'll be good